# c3js json timeseries issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3

I'm having issues getting c3js' timeseries to work with my json data. Right now I'm getting a few errors, the most significant of which is "Error: Invalid value for  attribute x="NaN". It appears that my x values aren't being parsed correctly despite the fact that they are in the specified format. What could be the problem?

The code is here:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
          data: {
            json: [
              {"key": "2015-03-27", "value": "261"},
              {"key": "2015-03-28", "value": "177"},
              {"key": "2015-03-29", "value": "145"},
              {"key": "2015-03-30", "value": "145"},
              {"key": "2015-03-31", "value": "145"},
              {"key": "2015-04-01", "value": "146"},
              {"key": "2015-04-02", "value": "125"},
              {"key": "2015-04-03", "value": "125"},
              {"key": "2015-04-04", "value": "133"},
              {"key": "2015-04-05", "value": "89"},
              {"key": "2015-04-06", "value": "89"},
              {"key": "2015-04-07", "value": "87"},         
              {"key": "2015-04-08", "value": "93"},
              {"key": "2015-04-09", "value": "163"},
              {"key": "2015-04-10", "value": "121"},
              {"key": "2015-04-11", "value": "153"},
              {"key": "2015-04-12", "value": "105"},
              {"key": "2015-04-13", "value": "105"},
              {"key": "2015-04-14", "value": "104"},
              {"key": "2015-04-15", "value": "113"},
              {"key": "2015-04-16", "value": "97"},
              {"key": "2015-04-17", "value": "114"},
              {"key": "2015-04-18", "value": "123"},
              {"key": "2015-04-19", "value": "118"},
              {"key": "2015-04-20", "value": "118"},
              {"key": "2015-04-21", "value": "114"},
              {"key": "2015-04-22", "value": "112"},
            ],
            keys: {
              x: 'key',
              xFormat:  '%Y-%m-%d',
              value: ['value']
            },
            type: 'area'
          },
          axis: {
            y: {
              label: { //ADD
                text: 'Y Label',
                position: 'outer-middle'
              }
            },
            x: {
              label: {
                text: 'X Label',
                position: 'outer-center',
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                  format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
              }
            }
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'right'
          },
          padding: {
            bottom: 20
          }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ertdnh2m/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"key": "2015-03-27", "value": "261"},
```

should be

```
{"key": 20150327, "value": "261"},
```

since it's expecting a number and the `-` can't be parsed into a number

Comment: This resolved the error. I now have to fix the formatting (http://jsfiddle.net/y3ycup25/) but at least I have something that resembles a chart. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `axis.x` formatting is wrong. It works fine as is with just changing that:

```
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
          },
          label: {
            text: 'X Label',
            position: 'outer-center'
          }
        }
```